# How to generate access token for Dataverse APIs

Tags: azure, rest, azure-active-directory, office365api, dataverse

I have a requirement to fetch the details from the Dataverse tables using the REST APIs and to do the same I need to generate the access token to send the valid Authorization header. I have gone through the [Use OAuth authentication with Microsoft Dataverse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/authenticate-oauth) and [Register an app with Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/walkthrough-register-app-azure-active-directory#create-an-application-registration) and followed the steps. Now to generate the access token I am using the POST method with `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token` endpoint with and passing the grant_type as `client_credentials`, resource as `https://management.core.windows.net/` along with client id and client secret with content type as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. But I am getting **AADSTS901002: The 'resource' request parameter is not supported.**

---

**EDIT**

In the API Permission tab I have added the delegated permission.

[image]

In the Authentication tab, I haven't selected any type for flow, Do I need to change here?

[image]

Also please note that In the Token Configuration tab no claims or group has been added yet and Expose API tab no scope and authorized client application is added. Please let me know if I need to do any changes here.

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

When I do not pass the resource param and send the scope with `https://{orgId}.crm5.dyanamics.com/.default` along with client_id, client_secret and grant_type I am able to get the access token, but when I use this token to fetch the data using `https://{orgId}.crm5.dyanamics.com/api/data/v9.0/accounts` I am getting *The user is not a member of the organization*

Answer (score 0):

The error **AADSTS901002: The 'resource' request parameter is not supported** indicates that the resource provided in the request is not correct.

As you are trying to generate access token for Dataverse API, the resource should be below:

```
https://admin.services.crm.dynamics.com/
```

Comment: Thanks, I have to generate the access token from the postman with the suggested resource value but I am getting the same message. Do I need to pass any additional details in the request as param or headers?

Comment: What is the scope you added? Does your app registration have user_impersonation delegated permission for dataverse api?

Comment: Hello RamaraoAdapa-MT, Previously I was not sending any scope but I have tried with `openid offline_access` and I am getting the same *AADSTS901002: The 'resource' request parameter is not supported.\* with resource as `https://admin.services.crm.dynamics.com/`

Comment: I have also updated the question with more details on configurations, currently, I do have the delegated permission added. Please let me know if any changes are required that. Thanks

Comment: You need to grant admin consent for user_impersonation permission. Also in the authentication tab, please check both access token and id token. You do not need to add any scope for this app registration

Comment: I have granted the admin consent in API Permission and it shows the status in green Granted for {org}. I have also marked both checkboxes in the Authentication tab. But I am getting the `same message AADSTS901002: The 'resource' request parameter is not supported`. Can you please guide me on it? Thanks

Comment: I have tried a few ways and I am able to get the access token but with that token, I am getting 403, not sure I am going in the correct direction or not. Thanks

Comment: Can you try with scope as user_impersonation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240190/discussion-between-rvp-and-ramaraoadapa-mt).